# Errors compiling Angular 15 project after upgrading from angular 6

Tags: angular, build

I have spend two days upgrading an angular 6 project to angular 15.

After I fixed several npm i depedency problem and other several ng serve errors, I only see three errors, but I dont know how fix them.

I have deleted node_modules, package-lock.json, executed npm cache-clean --force but it doesnt work.

This is the ng serve output:

```
$ ng serve
****************************************************************************************
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally.

It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.


DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 494.99 kB |                74.12 kB
scripts.js            | scripts       | 123.41 kB |                33.99 kB
main.js               | main          | 119.31 kB |                29.25 kB
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 119.31 kB |                29.23 kB
runtime.js            | runtime       |   1.24 kB |               670 bytes


| Initial Total | 858.25 kB |               167.24 kB


Build at: 2023-07-18T12:25:14.625Z - Hash: 396927dc64846961 - Time: 38628ms


Warning: 1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
.custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang


./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.


./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from 
./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):

Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.


Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - The target entry-point "angular-framework" 
has missing dependencies:

 - @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/modal/modal




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4250, open your browser on         
http://localhost:4250/ **


× Failed to compile.
```

This is my angular, npm, node version:

[image]

And this is the project dependencies:

[image]